# How do I dynamically create forms with Python Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have a large model which I have defined in my models.py file and I have the form which serves it. Do I have to explicitly state each field for the form or is there a way to dynamically create this so I don't have repetition in my code?

forms.py

```py
class CustomerForm(FlaskForm):  # must be a better way

    """ Declarative Form base class responsible for customers
        variable names match customers/models.py and in the corresponding HTML files """

    tpi_name = StringField('Enter Your Name')
    tpi_ref = StringField('Enter Your Email')
    company_name = StringField('Company Name (*)', validators=[InputRequired()])
    company_type = StringField('Company Type')
    company_reg = StringField('Company Registration Number')
```

and forms.py

```py
class Post(db.Model):  # Must be a better way

    """ Creates the table Post and models the structure of the database table """
    tpi_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    tpi_ref = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    company_type = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    company_reg = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
```

So there is a lot of repetition here, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

I've not personally tried this, but came across this: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/60/

Sounds like that's discussing what you're trying to achieve if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: Go ahead and add some of the important points from the link that would be helpful to the OP so they don't have to follow the link

Comment: Repeating information that already exists is not useful. Pointers to documentation are more than appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Till, the only issue is the docs are outdated and I cant seem to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like using flask-admin library: https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

> How does it work? The basic concept behind Flask-Admin, is that it lets you build 
>   complicated interfaces by grouping individual views together in classes: Each web page
>   you see on the frontend, represents a method on a class that has explicitly been added 
>   to the interface.
>
> These view classes are especially helpful when they are tied to particular database 
>   models, because they let you group together all of the usual Create, Read, Update, 
>   Delete (CRUD) view logic into a single, self-contained class for each of your models.

Example:

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

# Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy initialization here

admin = Admin(app, name='microblog', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
admin.add_view(ModelView(Post, db.session))
```